# Query firebase data in Android

Tags: android, firebase

I want to query the data from firebase.
But I meet some problem.
This is my firebase data  [click me show the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmexG.jpg)

```
Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("http//.....");
Query queryRef= myFirebaseRef.child("0912345678").orderByChild("coffeeNo").equalTo("002");

     queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    // do some stuff once

                    if (snapshot.getValue() == null) {
                        txtMyCoffee.setText("No data");
                    }
                    else{
                            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren())
                            {
                                Coffee userCoffee = dataSnapshot.getValue(Coffee.class);
                                date = userCoffee.getDate();
                                txtMyCoffee.setText(date+" Success!");
                            }
                        }
                }  @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                }
            });
```

but when  I Run this code , the txtMyCoffee's text will show me "No data".
How to resolve this problem ?
Thank you everyone !

Comment: there is an othe child under the `child("0912345678")` so you need to loop into them to not only the parent node, check John O'Reilly answer

Comment: @OussemaAroua hot to do ?

Comment: check the answer of John O'Reilly below. the link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44843802/4063532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference coffeeNoRef = rootRef.child("myCoffee").child("0912345678").child("20170627");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String coffeeNo = dataSnapshot.child("coffeeNo").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", coffeeNo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
coffeeNoRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

And the out will be:

```
003
```

Will work for sure.

Comment: I code " import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;"

and  in gradle code " apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'"

and
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }

but Android Studio show me "cannot resolve symbol 'database' "

Comment: Yes, you need to add `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'` to your build.gradle file or other version. It's mandatory. Find the correct version [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).

Comment: Can you take a look and see if `rootRef` and `coffeeNoRef` are not null?

Comment: For sure there is another problem. I verified the above code with a database structure similar with yours and works perfect.

Comment: You're welcome. If you think that my answer helped you in any way, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the single in which i can answer to your question is `stackoverflow` website.

Comment: I have another question :
If  My Firebase address is "https://......./myCoffee"
I can code  "myFirebaseRef .child("0912345678").child("20170627");"
to query  the data which under the "20170627" ?   (look the picture)

Comment: `Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://......./myCoffee");
myFirebaseRef .child("0912345678").child("20170627");
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren())
                            {
                                Coffee coffeeNo = dataSnapshot.getValue(Coffee.class);
                                txtMyCoffee.setText(coffeeNo.getDate());
              }`

Comment: Try to use the exact code that i provided you. It must work.

Comment: Is there everything ok?

Comment: You're welcome! So, yf you think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The type of query you're using will require you to iterate over children (can return more than one result)....so just include following in `onDataChanged`

```
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Coffee userCoffee = dataSnapshot.getValue(Coffee.class);
                        date = userCoffee.getDate();
                        txtMyCoffee.setText(date+" Success!");
                    }
```