# Firebase Querying many child based on one attribute value from one of them

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase storge

[image]

from the image above, I want to get all the milk powder based on the barcode of one of them

```
var query: Query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Barcode")
                    .orderByChild("itemBarcode")
                    .equalTo(read)
```

where 'read' is the barcode number I only get one item, 
I want instead to get all the item type and wight based on barcode number 
like:
 `SELECT itemWieght, itemName, itemPrice FROM barcode WHERE itemBarcode.itemType = itemType` or something like this

EDIT :

here is my part of the code if that's helps

```
var query: Query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Barcode")
                    .orderByChild("itemBarcode")
                    .equalTo(read)

                //Adapter
                query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                        myBarcodeArray?.clear()
                        for (r in p0.children) {
                            var infoHolder = r.getValue(BarcodeInfo::class.java)


                            myBarcodeArray!!.add(infoHolder!!)
                        }
                        val infoAdapter = BarcodeResultAdapter(applicationContext, myBarcodeArray!!)
                        view.listOfBarcodeResult.adapter = infoAdapter
                    }
                })
```

EDIT 2:
I tried also to use 2 queries, but it shows empty results

```
myDataRef?.child("Barcode")?.orderByChild("itemBarcode")?.equalTo(read)?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                    }
                    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                        var result = p0.getValue(BarcodeInfo::class.java)
                        myDataRef?.child("Barcode")?.orderByChild(result?.itemWeight.toString())?.equalTo(read)?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                            }
                            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                                for (r in p0.children){
                                    var holder = r.getValue(BarcodeInfo::class.java)
                                    myBarcodeArray!!.add(holder!!)
                                }
                                val infoAdapter = BarcodeResultAdapter(applicationContext, myBarcodeArray!!)
                                view.listOfBarcodeResult.adapter = infoAdapter
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
```

Comment: So y ou only want to get the value of the other properties? What is wrong with the shared code?

Comment: yes it will get the value of other properties, but that's not what I want, I want to get the value of all the other items with the same weight of the selected item with there properties and store them to myBarcodeArray

Answer (score 1):

If you want get all value inside an item (data snapshot) that mean you should catch a whole of that item so add your query to ListenerForSingleValueEvent

Reference : [Query firebase data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843752/query-firebase-data-in-android)

Comment: Sorry my programming skills are not that much, I didn't get the question and the answer in the reference, so here is my snapshot if that helps

Comment: @Dot what is the purpose of infoHolder ? the data snapshot you receive is the whole item you queried by itemBarcode and contain all other fields (itemPrice,itemType...)

Comment: I am expecting many objects, as for example all the milk powder that has "1800" weight stored to myBarcodeArray...

Comment: what ? your answer even make me more confuse. i dont know what myBarcodeArray meaning but this is what your code should be (if i understanding your question correctly) : https://pastebin.com/jFtZA1Ar

Comment: my problem is not with the snapshot at all my snapshot is just fine, it is with the query, I just want to get all the same weight objects by the barcode number, but I don't know how to query it

Comment: oh, i read your comment above. Probably need two query : first to get the itemWeight of itemBarcode then query again with that itemWeight

Comment: YES!!!! that's would be a good idea thanks, ill try it now and tell you what happened immediately

Comment: it just shows empty space ... ill add my new query and snapshots to the next edit

Comment: are you sure "result?.itemWeight.toString()" will return itemWeight ?

Comment: Oh! now i checkd it, it returned null... but why ?

Comment: because you cant reach the snapshot's child without key "itemWeight". Check the reference in my origin post and see the answer with green tick to understand :)

Comment: well, it is referring to the itemType after many tries now but .... still shows empty :(

Comment: What do you mean ? Anyway, your approach is correct it just data/query has issue so just careful debug :)

Comment: Oh... man, I am really stupid, I found the issue but still, I don't know how to solve it... you see my query is nested so that's why it won't show anything, based on the first result it will erase the second result, now I need a way to get the type from one query and store it and use it for the second query, but I don't know-how, any idea?  T_T

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using "Kiet Phan" advice and used 2 query statement like this :

```
var query: Query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Barcode")
                    .orderByChild("itemBarcode")
                    .equalTo(read)
                query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
                    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                        myBarcodeArray?.clear()
                        for (r in p0.children) {
                            var infoHolder = r.getValue(BarcodeInfo::class.java)
                            type = infoHolder?.itemType.toString()
                        }
                        var query2: Query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Barcode")
                            .orderByChild("itemType")
                            .equalTo(type)
                        query2.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}

                            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                                for (r in p0.children) {
                                    var infoHolder = r.getValue(BarcodeInfo::class.java)
                                    type = infoHolder?.itemType.toString()
                                    myBarcodeArray!!.add(infoHolder!!)
                                }
                                val infoAdapter = BarcodeResultAdapter(applicationContext, myBarcodeArray!!)
                                view.listOfBarcodeResult.adapter = infoAdapter
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
```

thanks to everyone for help